# arm-none-eabi-ld cannot find -mcpu=cortex-m3

Tags: gcc, ld

> There is another question with similar naming but it was never resolved.

I installed `arm-none-eabi` gcc and binutils from the GNU Arm Embedded PPA on Ubuntu. This toolchain normally works fine.

Today however, in my Makefile, I link with `-march=armv7-m -mcpu=cortex-m3` as some of the options. This immediately causes ld to fail like this:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-ld -mcpu=cortex-m3 -march=armv7-m -Tcm3.ld # and some more options
arm-none-eabi-ld: unrecognised emulation mode: arch=armv7-m
Supported emulations: armelf
```

What have I done wrong? I can't seem to find any information about this!

---

I've also tested this with my other toolchain (CodeSourcery, March 2011). That toolchain normally works, but fails now too.

Should I be linking with `gcc` not `ld`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that linking with `gcc` rather than `ld` solves the problem. I can even pass in the linker script without having to use `-Wl,-T`.

I'm still open as to why `ld` didn't work in the first place.